# Unnecessary pass in defining exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

Often I will write a generic exception such as the following:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    "My custom exception."
    pass
```

This way I can check if that exception is the one I want in something like a `try/except` block. Yet `pylint` complains about this as follows:

> unnecessary-pass: Unnecessary pass statement

What's the rationale behind this complaint? And is there a more preferred way to do the above? Even the python docs suggest using something like that for a [user-defined exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions):

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for exceptions in this module."""
    pass
```

Comment: The CPython interpreter has a optimization command line argument `-OO` that ignores docstrings.

Comment: @KlausD. Optimization seems not to break the anything in Python 3.7. A class definition with only the docstring and no pass will work just fine with the `-OO` flag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The rationale is that the string literal is a valid Python statement in the class body, therefore the `pass` is not needed to show indentation.

This is a style issue, so there is no definitive answer for how to fix this. If you feel that the `pass` is useful, I suggest disabling that warning in pylint.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out. In your opinion, how would you handle this?

Comment: Personally, since the docstring is an actual statement that has a useful effect, I would consider the `pass` redundant and leave it out. If the only line in the body was a comment, I would include the `pass`, because comments shouldn't make any difference to the code.